# ExoPlayer plays video but no sound, despite audiovolume on exoplayer set to 1.0

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have created an ExoPlayer in my app.  It is loading the video but I hear no audio.  In debug, I check that the audiovolume=1.0 for this ExoPlayer, this is indeed there.

Not sure how to trouble shoot why there isn't any sound?  The video url played in browser has sound.  The emulator volume is set to high...

Comment: try in a real device, emulator sometimes does not make sound